# Hessian-Free instead of LSTM for Recurrent Net Machine Translation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, lstm, machine-translation

Last year, Ilya Sutskever and collaborators came out with a [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf) about a recurrent LSTM net that learns sequence to sequence mappings for machine translation. It's somewhat surprising that the authors used LSTM instead of Hessian-Free to train this net since the first author was one of the innovators behind the development of Hessian-Free methods for recurrent nets ([citation](http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/532_icmlpaper.pdf)).

I was wondering if anyone has tried Hessian-Free for learning sequence to sequence mappings for machine translation. If so, does it work? Is its performance inferior to LSTM's in some way?

Comment: (I am not really familiar with either of these terms ... but why let that stop me?) I thought LSTM would be a network *architecture*, whereas "Hessian Free" sounds like an *optimization* (training) method?